# Sqlite bind or column index out of range but i've got the right number of parameters

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

My code is this:

```
db.run(`begin transaction;
  replace into players (user_id, role) values ($id, $role);
  update signed_up_users set finalised = 1 where user_id = $id;
  commit;`, { $id: id, $role: role}, err=>{
    if (err) {throw err;}
  });
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error: SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range
--> in Database#run('begin transaction;\n      replace into players (user_id, role) values (?, ?);\n      update signed_up_users set finalised = 1 where user_id = ?;\n      commit;', [ '123', 'INNOCENT', '123' ], [Function])
    at Object.exports.finalise_user (C:\whatever\file.js)
    at user.resolve_to_id.then.id (C:\whatever\file.js:52:14)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

If I understand the documentation correctly, I have the right amount of parameters and placeholders in my statement. So what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) actually says:

> #### Database#run(sql, [param, ...], [callback])
>
> Runs the SQL query […]
>
> #### Database#exec(sql, [callback])
>
> Runs all SQL queries in the supplied string.

Comment: That's what I'm using (?)

Comment: It says "query", not "queries".